# awk converting decimal numbers to 4-digit hexadecimal numbers inside string

Tags: bash, awk

I have file which look like this:

```
STH STH STH STH
232
STH STH STH STH
2342
2342
```

etc.

To be more specific. It contains lines of: 4 words all uppercase or numbers, separated by spaces or `'\n'`.

I would like to change only lines which contain numbers to hexadecimal numbers. I've tried writing script in `awk` but i gave up.

Solution, anyone?

Comment: Is the text file really an html file? The br in your post suggest it is.

Comment: @JohnMarkMitchell: no, see history.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$0+0==$0{ $0=sprintf("%x",$0) } 1' file
STH STH STH STH
e8
STH STH STH STH
926
926
```

or as @Cyrus suggested in a comment below:

```
$ awk '($0+0==$0){ $0=sprintf("%0.4x",$0) } 1' file
STH STH STH STH
00e8
STH STH STH STH
0926
0926
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide the expected output to go with your posted sample input.

Comment: I suggest to replace `%x` by `%0.4x`. See headline.

Comment: Good idea, I added that too as that would seem to match what the subject line says but lets see what the OP says and see if we can get some expected output posted. I have a feeling there's some onion peeling to be done.